# Tap on contacts name and take you to there specific page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to click on a contact from a list, and then be taken to that unqiue page. Its pretty much a contacts app like you have on your smartphone. So far I have a contacts list with all listed contact names and a contact information page that stores contacts data. I want to be able to click on the contacts name and it take me to a empty page that is unique to them. I will add detail to there unique page later.

I tried following some tutorials https://medium.com/@XensS/flutter-v-material-design-ii-7b0196e7b42d bu they are either outdated or elements have been changed, so it no longer works. All I want to do is be able to click persons name and it take me to a page belonging to them.

Answer (score 0):

Launch the new page on `onTap` of your `_ContactListItem`.

```
new _ContactListItem(_contacts[index], onTap: () {
  print("tapped $index");
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ContactDetailsPage()), //your new page
  );
})
```

Refer [here](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics/) more information about navigation.

Comment: @Dinesh_Balasubramanian So where exactly does that piece go? Also the link is broken.

Comment: Updated the link

Comment: @Dinesh_Balasubramanian I tried code but can't get the formatting. I updated the code

Comment: You have to put in itemBuilder(4 lines above which u edited)

Comment: @Dinesh_Balasubramanian I updated, but the onTap isn't recognized

Comment: Can u put a print and check inside onTap